# Count in 3 ul's

Tags: php, count

I'm trying to make 3 lists with my database output. I can't figure out how to place the end tags and count. I'm quite new to this, so I hope that someone can explain it for me.

**Here's my code**

```
<div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
<ul class="spillemaskiner">

    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM spillemaskine_anmeldelse ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $count = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    ?>

    <?php if ($count % 3 == 0) { ?>

    <a href="spillemaskine.php"><li><? echo $row['navn']; ?></li></a>

    <?php

        }
        else

    ?>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
<ul class="spillemaskiner">

    <?php { ?>

    <a href="spillemaskine.php"><li><? echo $row['navn']; ?></li></a>

    <?php

        }
            $count++;

        else {
    ?>

</ul>

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
<ul class="spillemaskiner">

    <?php { ?>

    <a href="spillemaskine.php"><li><? echo $row['navn']; ?></li></a>

    <?php

        }
            $count+++;
        }

    ?>

</ul>
```

I have tried to place the else tag after each li so that it doesn't output a new column (col-md-4) each time. It needs to output a new li in each of the 3 ul.

Comment: You can't have 2 else statements for 1 if statement and you never close your while loop! Also your brackets are all over the place you can't really tell which one closes which statement

Comment: Can you show me an example of how it should look?